# how to display the name of the departments that has the least student count

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

how to write a query to display the name of the departments that have the least student count. Sort the result based on department name in ascending order

[image: Refer below schema diagram]

Comment: No pictures thanks. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: what do we get for doing your homework ? have you tried writing any query ? If yes, what is not working in your query.

Comment: Which database are you targetting, Oracle or MySQL? If oracle, which version of the database? Syntax for doing `[top-n]` queries varies accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
select d.department_name from 
(select dd.department_name, count(di.department_id) as id from student di
join department dd on di.department_id=dd.department_id group by dd.department_name) d,
(select min(count(*)) as new from student group by department_id) d2
where d.id=d2.new;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select d.department_name from Department d, Student s where 
d.department_id = s.department_id
group by d.department_name
having count(s.student_id)<=all
(select count(s.student_id) from Department d, Student s where 
d.department_id = s.department_id
group by d.department_name)
order by department_name;
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

```
select d.department_id, d.department_name 
from Department d
join Student s on d.department_id = s.department_id
group by d.department_id
having count(s.student_id) = (select min(count(s2.student_id))
                              from student s2 
                                    join department d2 
                                    on s2.department_id = d2.department_id 
                               group by d2.department_id) 
order by d.department_name
```

You must join the 2 tables to have the needed information.

You'll also have to group them by the selected information such that you can count the students.

And lastly, you place the condition. Needing a subquery to retrieve the minimum number of students.

Answer (score -1):

```
select department_name
  from Department
    join Student
     on Department.department_id=Student.department_id
       having count(*) in
        ( select min(count(*)) from Student group by department_id)
        group by Department.department_id,department_name
        order by department_name asc;
```

Comment: Could you explain why this is a viable solution?